# Adding MySQL servers/ data nodes into database clustering without restarting mysql cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster, mysql-cluster

I currently have mysql clustering up and running. For high scalability is there a way to include either mysql node, data nodes, or management nodes without restarting the entire cluster. I wish to understand how is it implement or is there a documentation I can read. I believe only the latest version can support this. I am running NDB 7.0. I am aware that I am able to add the nodes online, but it requires me perform a rolling restart.

What other approach I can take to implement this without restarting in my network?

Answer (score 2):

Second link in google points to the MySQL FaQ:

**B.10.23: Can I add data nodes to a MySQL Cluster without restarting it?**

In MySQL Cluster NDB 7.0 and later, it is possible to add new data nodes to a running MySQL Cluster without taking it offline. For more information, see Section 16.5.12, [“Adding MySQL Cluster Data Nodes Online”.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-online-add-node.html)

For other types of MySQL Cluster nodes, a rolling restart is all that is required (see Section 16.5.4, “Performing a Rolling Restart of a MySQL Cluster”).

(In MySQL Cluster NDB 6.3 and earlier releases, it was not possible to add new data nodes without shutting down and restarting the MySQL Cluster.)